# cscope : go back in results window.

Tags: usability, cscope

How can i go back in the cscope results window. Pressing space takes me to the next page of results ,but what is the key to previous page of results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use this:

```
<Space>
Display next set of lines.
+
Display next set of lines.
-
Display previous set of lines.
```